# layered navigation - best way to edit robots meta tag when 0 results

Tags: magento-1.6

I'm trying to decide the best\most efficient way to detect that the product collection on the category pages contain no results and change the metarobots tag on the head block. I already do something similar using an observer for urls with sort direction parameters etc but the event i use (controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view) is too early to inspect the product collection, or at least i think it is!

I'm a user of amasty's improved navigation so the layered navigation is a little non standard, but i know the extensions code well enough to modify it if given a pointer in the right direction.

So, any ideas on the best/most efficient way to achieve this? thanks for your time.

Comment: Nobody? would really like some input here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amasty contacted me with a suggestion for this (thanks amasty). They suggested overriding the toolbar block and setting this after the pager's collection had been instantiated. Seems to work very well, thanks.